# Debian fails to install updates

Tags: debian-based, debian-stretch

When I try to poweroff the laptop this pops up.

Image:[Install pending updates option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovvmC.png)

But when Click it and poweroff the laptop the update fails at 0%.

How to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Open up the terminal
Enter:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo shutdown -r now
```

This will perform system updates. The last line will reboot.